# Setting a Datagrid Column to read only during run time

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I have a datagrid, not a datagridview, where I wan to make a column read only if radio button is checked or not.

So I define the column dynamically from a sql query:

```
Dim bool_col As New FormattableBoolColumn 
bool_col.HeaderText = "Bool Colunm"
bool_col.MappingName = "bool_col"
```

Also on the form are two radio buttons, lets call them A and B.
When A is checked I want to set the bool_col to read only is true.
When B is checked I want to set the bool_col to read only is false.

Let me know if anything else is needed.  I'm using the Click event but I can't figure out how to find the column in the Datagrid and set it to read only.  Spent all afternoon trying to do that and searched everything I can think of with no luck.
And I can't change it to a datagridview unfortunately.  Time and and money constraints on the project prohibit this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the column you can add a check:

```
bool_col.ReadOnly = RadioButtonA.Checked
```

So the read only property of the column will be true if A is checked and false if A is not.

Now this assumes that your radio buttons are in a group so only one of the two can be checked at a time.

If the radio buttons are not in a group then use:

```
If RadioButtonA.Checked Then
bool_col.ReadOnly = true
else if RadioButtonB.Checked Then
bool_col.ReadOnly = false
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only seems to work at time of creation.  What If i want to do it while the form is running.  A or B can change at run time and i want to set the column to read only or not depending on that change.

Comment: You can use the oncheckchanged event of the radio buttons with auto postback =true

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not using ASP, just a VB form in windows.  I guess I added the wrong tag in vb.net.  Doesn't appear postback exists. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: fro that to work you would have to recreate the grid oncheckchanged event of the radio button.  the concept is the same you just have to handle it in a different manner.  basically you will have to tell the form to recreate the grid any time that that control is checked.  If this has a lot of data in it or additional controls, this will become a memory suck quite quickly.